# Mongodb search and do operation at same time

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Is it possible for java to ask mongodb to only return data which has been calculated?
I need to retrieve data which `date1 - date2 < 10`.
If it's static date, it's like :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(date1).gt(someDate));
```

I need something like :

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(date1-date2).lt(10));
```

but I get error in `date1-date2` because the operator - is undefined for the argument string.

Comment: Can you calculate date3 (=date1-date2) before hand, and then send that date as a criteria?

Comment: I can't because the date1 and date2 is always different for each data.. @MordechayS

Comment: I don't understand. Are tou sure you can't writeba method that takes as parameter an original date + offset, and returns an offsetd date?

Comment: yes, I can't think of a way to count the date before hand @MordechayS

example of data:
`[{'id1','date1','date2','statusA'},{'id2','date3','date4','statusA'}]`

If I write another method, the solution will be :
`Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(status).is('statusA'));`

And after I get all the data which status is 'statusA', then I need to loop one by one all the data and count date1-date2 to know whether date1-date2 < 10.